# How to pick specificed values from array in PHP?

Tags: php

This is variable **$msg** returns this output from paypal response:

```
Array ( 
[mc_gross] => 7000.00 
[protection_eligibility] => Ineligible 
[address_status] => unconfirmed 
[payer_id] => SEVC3VYVYC8NS 
[tax] => 0.00 
[address_street] => Minicraft 5 
[payment_date] => 13:29:34 Jun 10, 2016 PDT 
[payment_status] => Pending 
[charset] => windows-1252 
[address_zip] => 11580 
[first_name] => Joe
[payer_email] => joe@hiskaya.com
)
```

I tried to get **$msg['payment_date']** and **$msg['payer_email']**, then they return empty blank strings in email body, I don't know why.

EDITED FOR SOMEONE WHO WANTS REVELANT CODE:

I created my own lib which it can send email, it's my own function, not revelant.

```
$msg = print_r($request, true);
$pay_date = $msg['payment_date'];

    sendMail([
      'subject' => 'Payment has been received',
      'body' => "Date: ".$pay_date.",
      'to_email' => 'someone@ail.com',
      'to_name' => 'Joe',
    ]);
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: can you explain where it is actually used means give the example where and how you use it

Comment: @DhavalPurohit  It's not big deal, I don't remember how to pick specificed from this array, so in this case "how to get a value from key Payment_date" ?

Comment: If `$msg` really has a value you showed us - then `$msg['payment_date']` will work fine. If it doesn't - this means that you either not showing us right value of `$msg` or your values are changed somewhere.

Comment: @u_mulder I think `$msg = print_r($request, true);` it just displays a text, I assume it's not converting to array

Comment: Start with reading http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-returnvalues

Comment: you just missed the " after $pay_date. it should "" and also check with print_r($msg) to check that it an array or object. if its an object then you should try $msg->payment_date to get the date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#refsect1-function.print-r-returnvalues)

> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string.

This means that `$msg` is a string. And definitely has **no** `payment_date` key.

I don't know why you assign `$request` value to another variable, you can use it:

```
sendMail([
  'subject' => 'Payment has been received',
  'body' => "Date: " . $request['payment_date'],
  'to_email' => 'someone@ail.com',
  'to_name' => 'Joe',
]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I got your answer, It was my mistake, I was exahusted to notice the error and my mind is literally out of ammo